# How can I plot an address list in Google Maps?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a 14 page PDF with a list of addresses in it. I'd like to see the addresses on a map.

Is there a website that can extract the addresses from the document and put them on a map?

Answer (score 2):

See this thread on plotting map points from excel entries. If you can get the .pdf information into a spreadsheet, these services might be able to help:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/baw9A5LuS3o

Sorry I can't be more specific, but the thread lists various sites that do allow map plotting based on address info.

Answer (score 0):

[batchgeo.com](http://batchgeo.com/) lets you paste a table of addresses, choose which columns represent which parts of the address, and then it puts all the addresses on a Google map.

Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.maptive.com/ worked for me beautifully. It's free for less than 250 addresses.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little late to the party here, but badger maps is fantastic geocoding resource as well.